# Curve Background in Slider in Android

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a created a slider using horizantalscrollview and inside that I added a  linearlayout to add view items

```
 <HorizontalScrollView>
            <LinearLayout>
                 view items will be here
            </LinearLayout>
 </HorizontalScrollView>
```

But I want to curve borders in slider according to the given image [image]

How can i curve the backgound only to displayed item in first and last , but please note that  this slider can have more than 8 elements , so when it slides , displayed corner images should curve , c1-c10 will be images

original image

[image]

Comment: Make a selector with round corners.

Answer (score 0):

create custom drawable by this code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:endColor="@color/black"
        android:startColor="@color/black" />

    <corners android:radius="3dp" />

</shape>
```

set this drawable in HorizontalScrollView background

i hope this will help you

Comment: nope it didnt work , c1 image corner should be curved

Answer (score 0):

Try out the below xml file code. Create a xml file inside your `res/drawable` folder with the name `rounder_corner_selector.xml` and paste below code:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="90dp"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#000000" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topRightRadius="15dp" />

</shape>
```

Apply the above file as background in your `HorizontalScrollView` as below:

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corner_selector" >
```

Comment: @GrlsHu , i imeplemted what you have sent , it applies for the background , but not for the thumb, ill attach the original image

Comment: @Mr.G Do you want to apply it to your images ?

Comment: yup , but i it should be visible left and right image at corner

Comment: Then you have to calculate your left and right corner image position and then you have to apply it accordingly.